# Is it compulsory to declare abstract class for abstract method?

Tags: php, oop

I have a below program

```
<?php
abstract class foo
{
    abstract public function callme();
    public function testing()
    {
        return $this->callme();
    }
}
class bar extends foo
{
    public function callme()
    {
        return "hello";
    }   
}

$objBar = new bar();
echo $objBar->testing();

?>
```

I defined `abstract class foo`. Is it compulsory to write abstract before class ? Because if i removed abstract i am getting fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it contains [abstract](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) methods.

By declaring a method as abstract you are saying that in order to use this class, extending classes must implement the abstract method.

Your foo class cannot be instantiated unless `callme` is implemented, hence it must be declared abstract.

---

These concepts are perhaps better explained with a real world example than your standard `abstract class Vehicle`, `class Car extends Vehicle` tutorials.

Let's say we have a reporting system that does some querying on the database.

We find that all reports must be implemented in a standard way to share code and help with future maintenance.

So we define:

```
abstract class Report 
{

}
```

For the sake of argument, all of our reports require a database connection.

```
abstract class Report 
{
    /** @var PDO */
    protected $dbh;

    public function __construct (PDO $dbh) 
    {
         $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }  

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    abstract public function getData();

}
```

Here we have also decided that all of our reports must implement a public getData method that returns an array.

This means:

- We can ensure all our reports have a database connection
- We can instantiate and then run each report in the same way

The abstract class definition has enforced the way we consume this code and makes sure that every type of report, regardless of which developer on your team wrote it, conforms to the convention we have decided.

Other code is then able to select a report from user input, run it, and do something with the result of getData (such as writing it to a CSV file) knowing that it will be an array.